# Adding text using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, text

I am trying to build a graph using matplotlib, and I am having trouble placing descriptive text on the graph itself.

My y values range from `.9 to 1.65`, and x ranges from the dates `2001 to 2021` and are sourced from a datetime series.

Here are the basics of what I am working with:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
```

I know that I have to use `ax.text()` to place any text, but whenever I try to enter basically any values for the x and y coordinates of the text, the entire graph disappears when I re-run the cell. I have plotted the following line, but if I use the same coordinates in `ax.text()`, I get the output I just described. Why might this be happening?

`plt.axhline(y=1.19, xmin=.032, xmax=.96)`

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `y` argument in the `axhline` method is in **data coordinates**, while the `xmin` and `xmax` arguments are in **axis coordinates**, with `0` corresponding to the far left of the plot, and `1` corresponding to the far right of the plot. See [the `axhline` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html) for more information.

On the other hand, both the `x` and `y` arguments used in the `text` method are in **data coordinates**, so you position text relative to the data. However, you can change this to axis coordinates using the `transform` parameter. By setting this to `ax.transAxes`, you actually indicate that the `x` and `y` arguments should be interpreted as axis coordinates, again with `0` being the far left (or bottom) of the plot, and `1` being the far right (or top) of the plot. In this case, you would use `ax.text` as follows:

```
ax.text(x, y, 'text', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Again, see [the `text` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) for more information.

However, it sounds like you might want to combine data and axis coordinates to place your text, because you want to reuse the arguments from `axhline` for your text. In this case, you need to create a transform object that interprets the `x` coordinate as *axis coordinate*, and the `y` coordinate as *data coordinate*. This is also possible by creating a **blended transformation**. For example:

```
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

# create your ax object here

trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(x_transform=ax.transAxes, y_transform=ax.transData)

ax.text(x, y, 'text', transform=trans)
```

See the [Blended transformations](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations) section of the transformations tutorial for more information.

In short, you can refer to the following figure to compare the results of these various transformations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(0, 2)
ax.set_ylim(0, 2)

# note that the line is plotted at y=1.5, but between x=1.6 and x=1.8
# because xmin/xmax are in axis coordinates
ax.axhline(1.5, xmin=.8, xmax=.9)

# x and y are in data coordinates
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'A')

# here, x and y are in axis coordinates
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'B', transform=ax.transAxes)

trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(x_transform=ax.transAxes, y_transform=ax.transData)
# here, x is in axis coordinates, but y is in data coordinates
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'C', transform=trans)
```

[image]